# The aspect of psychological resultatives

Tags: grammar, aspect

Take a look at the psychological resultatives:

(1) a. Facebook’s apps have annoyed me into not using them.
b. The lines of the prose are what fascinated me into making the painting.
c. Staff did not look happy. Almost depressed me out of buying a sandwich.

Are they punctual or gradual events?

Are the following sentences acceptable:

(2)  a. Recently football on TV has been annoying me so much that I stop watching it.
b. This whole issue is worrying me so much that I can't cope.

Are you able to make up similar contexts for psychological resultatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Take a look at the psychological resultatives:

They are simply resultatives: *She shouted herself **hoarse** / He beat the metal **flat** / She arrived **drunk**.*

> Are they punctual or <s>gradual</s> durative events?

That depends on the verb.

> Are the following sentences acceptable:

Yes.

Comment: I don't agree that they behave like the resultatives you've alluded to. The sentence She shouted herself hoarse is agentive and it affects her. But the examples I gave with the Object Experiencer verbs are not agentive.

Comment: @Arek I've amended my answer.

Comment: "Recently football on TV has been annoying me so much that I stop watching it." sounds odd to me. "stopped watching" would be more common. Unless you mean that every time it's on tv you watch for a bit then stop, in which case you should maybe reword it to indicate you watch for a short time on each occasion.

Comment: @StuartF I see "that I stop watching it." as the historic present": there does not seem to be anything wrong with it.